# Как задать стили в уже обработанной форме php

Tags: php, form

Подскажите пожалуйста, как задать стили в уже обработанном и выведенном на экран файле php?
И ещё такой вопрос, почему не отображается результат комментария?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['eduform']) && isset($_POST['comment']) && isset($_POST['courses'])) {
    $name = htmlentities($_POST['firstname']);
    $secondname = htmlentities($_POST['secondname']);
    $eduform = htmlentities($_POST['eduform']);
    $hostel = "нет";
    if (isset($_POST['hostel'])) $hostel = "да";
    $comment = htmlentities($_POST['comment']);
    $courses = $_POST['courses'];
    $output = "
     <html><head><title>Анкетные данные</title></head><body>Вас зовут: $name<br /> Ваша фамилия: $secondname<br /> Форма обучения: $eduform<br /> Требуется общежитие: $hostel<br /> Выбранный факультет: <ul>";
    foreach ($courses as $item) $output.= "<li>" . htmlentities($item) . "</li>";
    $output.= "</ul></body></html>";
    echo $output;
} else {
    echo "Введенные данные некорректны";
}
?>
```

```html
<h2>Анкета первокурсника</h2>
<form action="input.php" method="POST">
  <p>Введите имя:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" /></p>
  <p>Введите фамилию:</p>
  <input type="text" name="secondname" />
  <p>Форма обучения: <br>
    <input type="radio" name="eduform" value="очно" />очно <br>
    <input type="radio" name="eduform" value="заочно" />заочно </p>
  <p>Требуется общежитие:<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hostel" />Да</p>
  <p>Выберите факультет: <br>
    <select name="courses[]" size="5" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="Факультет экономической информатики">ЭИ</option>
      <option value="Факультет экономики и права">ЭП</option>
      <option value="Факультет менеджмента и маркетинга">МиМ</option>
      <option value="Факультет международных экономических отношений">МЭО</option>
      <option value="Факультет консалтинга и международного бизнеса">КиМБ</option>
      <option value="Финансовый факультет">ФФ</option>
      <option value="ФАКУЛЬТЕТ подготовки иностранных граждан">ФПИГ</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>Краткий комментарий: <br>
    <textarea name="comment" maxlength="200"></textarea>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Выбрать" />
</form>
```

Comment: Просто совет - можно использовать одну конструкцию isset(): `isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['eduform'], $_POST['comment'], $_POST['courses'])`

Comment: стили задаются в css. коммент не отображается, потому что не выводишь.

Comment: С комментарием разобралась, а вот не пойму, как задать стили, когда уже выводится ответ?

Comment: Где конкретно нужно изменить стиль и после какого момента? После отправки формы, до отправки...

Comment: После отправки.